# Dúvida sobre o menor valor das notas

Tags: c

Estou com uma dúvida a respeito do teste condicional para armazenar o menor valor, não é bem uma dúvida, o problema é que quando imprime, o valor do menor valor fica 0.0, o que prejudica calcular a média corretamente, no maior valor deu certo, mas no menor não, o que poderia ser?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 5

int main(){
    int i, j;
    float notas[NUM];
    float media;
    float maior=0, menor=0;

        for(i=0; i<NUM; i++){
            scanf("%f", &notas[i]);
        }

        for(i=0; i<NUM; i++){

            if(notas[i] >= notas[i+1]){
                maior = notas[i];
            }
            else{
                maior = notas[i+1];
            }

        }

        for(i=0; i<NUM; i++){
            if(notas[i] < notas[i+1]){
                menor = notas[i];
            }
            else{
                menor = notas[i+1];
            }
        }


        for(i=0; i<NUM; i++){

            media += notas[i];

        }

        media -= maior;//cálculo da média da escola

                    printf("%.1f %.1f %.1f\n", maior, menor, media);

                        printf("\n");

            for(i=0; i<NUM; i++){
                printf("%.1f ", notas[i]);
            }

    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Esse cálculo da média não faz sentido, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

O loop tá errado, na última iteração você compara o último valor do vetor com um valor fora dele. Aí pode pegar qualquer valor, inclusive o 0.0.

Faça assim:

```
for(i=0; i<NUM-1; i++){
    if(notas[i] < notas[i+1]){
        menor = notas[i];
    }
    else{
        menor = notas[i+1];
    }
}
```

Itera até NUM-1. Faça isso pro maior valor também, pra evitar futuros erros.

Answer (score 2):

Esse algoritmo está muito complexo e tem muita coisa desnecessária. E usaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define NUM 5

int main(){
    float notas[NUM];
    float maior = 0, menor = INT_MAX, media;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        scanf("%f", &notas[i]);
        maior = notas[i] > maior ? notas[i] : maior;
        menor = notas[i] < menor ? notas[i] : menor;
        media += notas[i];
    }
    media /= NUM;
    printf("%.1f %.1f %.1f\n\n", maior, menor, media);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) printf("%.1f ", notas[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KEAfol). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mjglrykn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/GradeStats.c).

Dá para melhorar, não validei da melhor forma, até porque o original não fazia isso também, mas já é um ganho. Daria para evitar a comparação e usar operadores de bits, mas acho que não deseja isso, mesmo sendo mais rápido.

Fiz o cálculo da média do jeito correto, modernizei o código e simplifiquei. Não sei se havia alguma obrigação de fazer algo daquele jeito, mas não faz sentido.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que assim, está correto.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM 5
int main() {

float notas[NUM];
int i;
float maior, menor, soma = 0;

for(i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
    scanf("%f", &notas[i]);
}
maior = notas[0]; menor = notas[0];
for(i=0; i<NUM; i++) {

    if(maior < notas[i + 1]) {
        maior = notas[i];
    }
    if (menor > notas[i + 1]) {
            menor = notas[i];
    }
        soma += notas[i];
}

printf("Maior: %.2f\nMenor: %.2f\n", maior, menor);
printf("Media: %.2f\n", soma / NUM);

    return 0;
}
```